# selenium UnhandledAlertException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a site where alert show 2 times.
Scenario:

- First load site
- After loading press submit button and its show browser alert
- Accept alert then take sometimes
- Then again shows browser  alert with success message and its accept (2nd alert see console)

> For browser issue sometimes 2nd alert, not show and I handle it by catch

```
            try {

                    driver.switchTo().alert();
                    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                    // Wait for Alert to be present
                    Alert myAlert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

                    myAlert.accept();



                }


                catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException e){
                    driver.navigate().refresh();

                }
                catch (org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException e){

                    driver.navigate().refresh();

                }
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : see console}
>     (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)

Manage this error by UnhandledAlertException but somehow its not working..Can anyone suggest me how can i handle this

Comment: Is the alert being shown through onWindowLoad event?

Comment: yes it's showing by  on window load event

Comment: Well that is your problem, onWindowLoad gets executed even before Selenium can patch up the alert methods and hence it won't be able to dismiss the alert. If it is a app you control then ask the developers to not use onWindowLoad

Comment: Thanks, Let's talk to the developer